# CSS not supported in IE 9 for Dropdownlist

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-9

I have a dropdownlist which is made in `HTML5`. But it is not taking the CSS in IE 9. 
Please see the html for the same.

```
<div class="lbl-drop">
    <label class="lbl">
      <div class="dropdown dropdown-dark">
        <select class="dropdown-select">
            <option selected=""> Date Added: Latest Firt</option>
            <option>Short Option</option>
            <option>This Is A Longer Option</option>
        </select>
      </div> 
    </label> 
</div>
```

The above was the html code,

Please see the CSS for your reference:-

```
<style type="text/css">
   .dropdown:before {
        border-bottom-style: solid;
        border-top: none;
    }
    .dropdown:after {
        margin-top: 7px;
        border-top-style: solid;
        border-bottom: none;
    }
    .dropdown:before, .dropdown:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        top: 9px;
        right: 10px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border: 4px dashed;
        border-color: #888 transparent;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    .dropdown:before {
        border-bottom-style: solid;
        border-top: none;
    }
    .dropdown:after {
        margin-top: 7px;
        border-top-style: solid;
        border-bottom: none;
    }
</style>
```

Also some more CSS related to it which I forgot, Sorry

```
<style type="text/css">
.dropdown-dark {
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    /* -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset; */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset;
    /* box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset; */
    background: transparent;
    font-family: "Lato-Italic";
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #a5a5a5;
    border: 1px solid #a5a5a5;
    outline: none;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Follow this link to see how you can add you won arrow and set it to always stay at the top. http://jsfiddle.net/x90Ldada/1/

Comment: Could you be more clear in your question about *what* doesn't work in Internet Explorer 9?

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it with jQuery as shown below

```js
 $(document ).ready(function() {
     $("select").after().addClass("color-change-select");
     $("select option").after().addClass("color-change");

});
```

```css
.color-change-select { /* for the select */
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    display: blcok;
    position: relative;
    border: solid 1px red!important;
    background-color: maroon;
}

.color-change { /* for the options */
    color: white;
    display: blcok;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
            <option> Date Added: Latest Firt</option>
            <option>Short Option</option>
            <option>This Is A Longer Option</option>
        </select>
```

[Follow this link to see how you can add your own link and get it to always stay at the top](http://jsfiddle.net/x90Ldada/1/)

**Note:** Using jQuery method will help combat browser issues